# Episode name of what I believe was The Outer Limits new series

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, androids, the-outer-limits

Episode name of what I believe was The Outer Limits new series, where an android squad is ambushed and killed, except the medic, who is captured by the "Creeter" who turns out to be a human, the creators of the androids, who rebelled and destroyed humanity. He captured the medic to try to save his pregnant mate, but she has died. The android kills him and goes home to his own wife and baby, who he tells to unplug for the night and get some rest.

The human defeated the android squad with primitive weapons such as a spear, and was much faster than them. They were spooked by the stories of creeters, but hadn't seen one in so long they weren't quick to believe in them. The humans were hiding in a cave, IIRC.

Comment: Are you sure this was *The Outer Limits*? I just read all the episode descriptions on Wikipedia, and they don't look like what you describe.

Comment: So did I. No luck, not sure by a long shot, but I believe it had the ending voice over about typical human creations turning on them type stuff.

Comment: My plot description is pretty good, as I recall the details fairly well. The human defeated the android squad with primitive weapons such as a spear, and was much faster than them. They were spooked by the stories of creeters, but hadn't seen one in so long they weren't quick to believe in them. The humans were hiding in a cave, IIRC.

Comment: Also it had high production values for a tv show of the time, very reminiscent of 90's outer limits.

Comment: The humans were called creeters because the androids bastardized the word creators, the human asked him if he knew the origin of the term.

Comment: Note:  Jonah was 36 seconds faster than me.  He gets the win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is *The Twlight Zone: ["Hunted"](http://www.tv.com/shows/twilight-zone-2002/hunted-202131/)* (2002)

This is an episode of the 2002 revival of *The Twilight Zone*

> In a futuristic society there hasn't been any murders or any violent
> crime for 50 years. But how did "mankind" accomplish this? Then comes
> word that a savage beast from the past known as a "creeter" has
> emerged in the woods outside of the city and killed (4) hikers. A
> volunteer military team of (5) soldiers is sent to seek out and
> destroy the enemy and restore peace to the civilized society. But the
> savage killer proves to be a difficult foe to capture and the creeter
> is able to kill (3) of the soldiers while taking a 4th hostage. The
> creeter uses the captured soldier to lure the last remaining soldier
> to his hideout. But once inside the hideout we learn that the creeter
> has spared this soldier because the creeter believes the soldier can
> help save the creeter's pregnant wife. Yes, it seems that the creeter
> is in fact human. And the soldiers and the peaceful futuristic
> society, not human! They are all cyborgs. The soldier manages to
> surprise the creeter (which stands for "creator" by the way) and kill
> him. Thus killing the last known human. And with that the cyborgs
> peaceful way of life is restored.

From the transcript:

**The word "creator" evolved into "kreetor."**

> "Where do you think "kreetor" comes from?
> 'Creator.' We created you."

**The kreetor wanted the android to care for his pregant wife.**

> ANDROID: You can talk?
>
> KREETOR: I saw you care for that soldier last night.  She was
> pregnant. But something went wrong. I brought you here to stop the
> bleeding.
>
> ANDROID: Help you?

Comment: I somehow missed it when reading the TZ descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

#### *The Twilight Zone: Hunted*:

> In a futuristic society there hasn't been any murders or any violent crime for 50 years. But how did "mankind" accomplish this? **Then comes word that a savage beast from the past known as a "creeter" has emerged in the woods outside of the city and killed (4) hikers**. A volunteer military team of (5) soldiers is sent to seek out and destroy the enemy and restore peace to the civilized society. **But the savage killer proves to be a difficult foe to capture and the creeter is able to kill (3) of the soldiers while taking a 4th hostage. The creeter uses the captured soldier to lure the last remaining soldier to his hideout. But once inside the hideout we learn that the creeter has spared this soldier because the creeter believes the soldier can help save the creeter's pregnant wife.** Yes, it seems that the creeter is in fact human. And the soldiers and the peaceful futuristic society, not human! They are all cyborgs. The soldier manages to surprise the creeter (which stands for "creator" by the way) and kill him. Thus killing the last known human. And with that the cyborgs peaceful way of life is restored.
>   -  [Source](http://www.tv.com/shows/twilight-zone-2002/hunted-202131/)

And:

> In the future, almost all crime has been eliminated; **squads of Civil Security Guards perform what little law enforcement is necessary. One such squad is called into action when the Kreetor, a genetically altered creature of a species long thought extinct, has returned to menace this idyllic future society.**
>
> **After four hikers are killed, the Guards attempt to hunt down the creature but soon it becomes unclear who is hunting whom.**
>
> At the end, the Kreetor is revealed to be a human ("Kreetor" being another word for "Creator"). **Jeffrey Freed, the commander of the unit, and his kind - everyone else left on Earth - all turn out to be androids who have emulated human society.**
>
> **The Kreetor abducts Freed and asks him to help his pregnant wife, but Freed refuses and kills the Kreetor.**
>
> **Returning to his home, Freed sees his wife with their baby as he tells her "unplug" it so that it can get some sleep. After Forest Whitaker's narration about the "evolution or exinction" of man is heard, Mrs. Freed says "Good night" to her baby and unplugs it for the night.**
>   -  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunted_(The_Twilight_Zone))

#### Closing narration:

> God created humanity in his image. Humans created Jeffrey Freed and his kind in their image. Extinction or evolution? I guess it all depends on your point of view.

Comment: Wad, stealing my answer. :) I got there first though.